# Detect CPU slowdown due to overheating

Tags: cpu, cooling

How do you detect when the Pi is slowing down its clockspeed due to overheating?

I know I can find the "current" CPU speed by running:

```
sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
```

and I can see it fluctuate, but I don't know if it's changing because the CPU's getting too hot or it's just inactive.

Answer (score 1):

If your Rpi is has a display (and you use an original config.txt file), a small icon will flash on the top right corner of the display, when the CPU is limited, representing lack of power (thunder icon), or overheat (thermometer).

You you don't have display, you still can see the point of temperature where CPU is throttling, with the command :
`vcgencmd get_config int`
at line : `temp_limit=`

and the current cpu temperature and clock with :
`vcgencmd measure_temp && vcgencmd measure_clock arm`